# Frontend app running inside docker container not accessible from browser

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

Here is the dockerfile for my react front end app

```
# Use an official Node.js runtime as the base image
FROM node:16.13.1

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Build your React app for production (you might need to adjust this based on your setup)
# RUN npm run build

# Expose the port your app will run on (typically 80 for HTTP)
EXPOSE 5173

# Define the command to run your app (start script in package.json)
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Here is the command i used to build the image

```bash
docker build -t react-frontend-image .
```

Here is the command i used to run the container

```bash
docker run -it -p 5173:5173 --name react-frontend-container react-frontend-image
```

After that when i try to access the site on browser at localhost:5173 i get this error
This page isn’t working

Here are the logs while running the container

VITE v4.4.5  ready in 517 ms

➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
➜  Network: use --host to expose
➜  press h to show help

The app is working just fine when I run it locally.

Comment: Does your container produce any logs? If it does please include them in the question!

Comment: added the comment just now

Comment: Looks like your app is only listening to `localhost`, when running inside a container `localhost` is referring to the interface of the container, not your computer. This is probably why you can not reach it from the outside. Either run the docker container with `--network host` or configure your app to listen to the `0.0.0.0` interface

Comment: Changing the run command to docker run -it -p 5173:5173 --network host --name react-frontend-container react-frontend-image didn't work it says
This site can’t be reached 
localhost refused to connect.
configuring the app to listen on 0.0.0.0 worked.

Comment: Good! I posted an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the container logs it seems like your app is only listening on the `127.0.0.1` interface.
When running inside a container youcan not connect to the `127.0.0.1`.

You should configure the app to listen on `0.0.0.0` (probably via `CMD ["npm", "run", "dev", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]`)